# How to upload data to Allen-Bradley PanelView C300?

Tags: controller, screen, plc

As I understood there are two ways to upload, by an usb pen drive and connect usb to laptop. I try by a pen drive. I did, but after few times is doesn't recognize my usb pen drive. So I am trying to connect directly, but the driver doesn't wont to install from their website, it shows failed (windows 10), there is in device manager only a serial port device, but I need USB RNDIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive connected by miniusb. I had to install windows 7 on virtual machine, then the driver installed correctly.